# Why is OmniThreadLibrary limited to 60 threads when .Net's limit is 32768?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, omnithreadlibrary

I was recently comparing OmniThreadLibrary and ThreadPool that is in .NET and I found that Omni is much more restricted in maximum threads — **60 allowed** — while .NET can go up to **32768** in .NET 4.0.

Why such a limit?

Comment: there is possibly another reason. and that is stack size. the default in Delphi is to allocate 1MB of address space to the stack of each thread. on a 32 bit process you will run into issues around the 1000 thread count with out of memory exceptions being thrown, despite there being ram unused. this is due to the 2.1GB available address space of a 32 bit app.

Comment: @MikeT by the way this can be bypassed if you use multiprocess with IPC. Then you can have 60 + threads.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's an historic choice that once may be lifted. The limit is only there on the threadpool implementation.

An explanation is given on [the website](http://otl.17slon.com/forum/index.php?topic=32.0), stating the following:

> The limitation of 60 concurrent threads only applies to the thread
>   pool. Thread pool is designed for fast execution of many small
>   requests, not as a storage for rarely-active threads.
>
> You can just skip thread pool and use OTL tasks directly. That way you
>   can create many hundreds of them.

The reason for this limit is that deep inside `[OtlTaskControl]TOmniTaskExecutor.WaitForEvent` uses MsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx which has this limitation. If a real need occurs for task pools with more than 60 concurrently running threads, this limitation could be circumvented.

Comment: Btw, the link is dead. The OTL forum appears to be dead.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately. There is an [issue report](https://code.google.com/p/omnithreadlibrary/issues/detail?id=59) for that, although I don't have any insights in if or when the forum will be restored.

Comment: Am I right in saying this limitation applies to the Parallel.For/Foreach functions?  If so, we would need to change our code to create the tasks manually because we require > 60 threads.  Is there a straightforward way in OTL to wait for a collection of tasks to complete (WaitFor or similar)?

Answer (score 1):

You can bypass this stuff by changing the following:

`FD_SETSIZE = 1024` in  `Winsock.pas`

`CMaxConcurrentWorkers = 1024;` in `OtlThreadPool.pas`