# How can I use more than 60 tasks in a task group?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, omnithreadlibrary

How can I use more than 60 tasks in a **Taskgroup**? I can loop from 0 to N and create tasks but that will not give me any message handling. I use OTL EventMontior for sending messages from tasks..

The reason I ask is because using Indy I am limited to 60 requests. However if I use a normal TThread I won't have these problems but I will have other problems etc.

> **.NET Thread Pool MAX:**
>
> - 1023 in Framework 4.0 (32-bit environment)
> - 32768 in Framework 4.0 (64-bit environment)

Answer (score 4):

According to `OtlTaskControl.pas` (based on v3.02 source), you can't exceed 64.  (Don't know where your 60 came from, but I admit not having tried to exceed it.)

`TOmniTaskGroup.WaitForAll` (approximately line #3300) uses the WinAPI function [`WaitForMultipleObjects`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms687025%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), and according to the MSDN documentation:

> The maximum number of object handles is MAXIMUM_WAIT_OBJECTS.

`MAXIMUM_WAIT_OBJECTS` is defined in `Windows.pas` (for XE3, at approximately line # 1017:

```
MAXIMUM_WAIT_OBJECTS = 64;
{$EXTERNALSYM MAXIMUM_WAIT_OBJECTS}
```

The declaration itself comes from `WinNT.h` from the SDK, which contains:

```
#define MAXIMUM_WAIT_OBJECTS 64     // Maximum number of wait objects
```

`WaitForMultipleObjects` returns an error code if you pass it a value higher than `MAXIMUM_WAIT_OBJECTS` as the `nCount` parameter. (The error code is returned if any value higher than `64` is send as the `nCount` parameter, which means this value is built into the implementation of the function itself.)

A quick review of the other API [Multiple-object Wait Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms687069%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#multiple-objectwaitfunctions) doesn't turn up anything else that will accept more than `MAXIMUM_WAIT_OBJECTS` items, either.

So the specific answer to your question is: The only way this can be done is to write your own replacement for the WinAPI's `WaitForMultipleObjects`, and then replace the `WaitForMultipleObjects` call in `TOmniTaskGroup.WaitForAll` with a call to your function instead. (That's a very massive undertaking, which is probably why it hasn't been done in OTL, and expecting someone to do it in an answer here would be pretty unrealistic.)

Answer (score 2):

According to an answer to [a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13458029/33732) (regarding the rationale for the limit), you can bypass the limit by changing the definitions of `FD_SETSIZE` in *Winsock.pas* and `CMaxConcurrentWorkers` in *OtlThreadPool.pas*. Set them to whatever limit you prefer. I cannot personally vouch for the advice, though.

Note that by modifying *Winsock.pas*, you remove the ability to use Delphi-provided run-time packages in your application. (You can still use packages you've compiled yourself; they just can't have the same names a the built-in packages.)

Comment: Rob, the question is not about OtlThreadPool but OtlTaskGroup.

Comment: As I said, I cannot vouch for the advice. I'm only repeating what I read, and according to Jachguate, I misunderstood what I read. You're in a better position to test this than I am.

Comment: @RobKennedy Why dont you allow my edit? The question is closed Let the people know how to do it!

Comment: I have no idea what you're talking about. I'm not preventing you from editing anything. What do you want to know how to do, that I haven't already told you?

Comment: I see. You [attempted to edit my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1207989), but the edit was rejected, although not by me. I'd have rejected it, too, and for the same reason. You need one more vote to open the question. I might yet incorporate some of your attempted edit into my answer.